# Google sheet query to output data with unique ID

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

**HI,**
I'm trying to make a Simple Inventory Management system for my work. 
So, I have a google sheet that helps me input Purchases on a `Purchase DB`, for sales `Sales DB` & `Current inventory list` to track my all products. (You will find the sheet below)

- Google Sheet: [click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d05o1RsAcP2r_SODlC37FpcAz0ER8xv6EjM_6aFm-l8/edit?usp=sharing)
  In my `Purchase DB` sheet I input all my purchases data than on sheet `Seles & Pur. Supt.` `Range B1:E`pull out the data combine the same item name into one name and sum the quantities of products & put them as the product's conditions are. 
  On my `Seles & Pur. Supt.` `Range A1:A` I'm running a formula that generates auto id for the products `Range B1:B`
- Query fore combine data: 
  `=QUERY('Purchase DB'!A1:F, "select C, sum(D),E,F group by C,E,F Order by C desc LABEL sum(D) 'Quantity'",1)`
- Auto ID generate: `=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B:B),if(ROW(B:B)=1,"Item ID",TEXT(ROW(A:A)-1,"0")),))`

Now the problem is every time I input data into my purchase tab data goes mixed up with the existing ID. 
Currently, it looks like this: 
[image]

In this image, you can see that there is a product called Tiger appaired twitch. which is what I wanted to be by the item conditions `New Product`
`Return Product` & all of the item has their won Item ID to represent them.
After adding a new Item name `Tiger 1` to the list
[image]

As you can see after I added a new item `Tiger 1` it moved to the top & change all the items id below. 
I wanted to be 
[image]

Every item should go down & have a higher ID number each time when I add a new Item to my database.
I'm looking for your help. So, Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a conceptual issue here:

- Since you are generating the ID on column A and fetching the other data using a QUERY (and ordering) on column B, the ID and the other data are not "committed". In other words, both A1 and A2 of `Seles & Pur. Supt.` will always update/run and return separate results, without any relation.
- The reason why `Tiger 1` appears first is the Combination of `Group by` and `Order by` clauses of `QUERY`. But since you are grouping data from `Purchase DB` this is also expected.

Proposed solutions:

- Create a new Spreadsheet to keep a relationship of ID/Item list and refactor your formulas in `Purchase DB` to reference and display the Item Id and data from this new  spreadsheet. Then whenever you have a new item, its data will be centralized in this spreadsheet and
- **(Recommended)** Sheets is not the best tool to keep a database nor manage data relations. For those reasons, I'd recommend considering the use of a relational database.